# PHP regex replacement doesn't match

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this regex to get house number of a street adress.

```
[a-zA-ZßäöüÄÖÜ .]*(?=[0-9])
```

Usually, the street is something like "Ohmstraße 2a" or something. At regexpal.com my pattern matches, but I guess preg_replace() isn't identical with it's regex engine.

```
$num = preg_replace("/[a-zA-ZßäöüÄÖÜ .]*(?=[0-9])/", "", $num);
```

Update:
It seems that my pattern matches, but I've got some encoding problems with the special chars like äöü

Update #2:
Turns out to be a encoding problem with mysqli.

Comment: Show us your complete replacement code you have so far. And why not use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-ZßäöüÄÖÜ .]`?

Comment: I'm still not quite familiar with regexes, so I just wanted to make sure it matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you want to **get** the house number then you should not **replace** it. So instead of `preg_replace` use `preg_match`.

I modified your regex a little bit to match better:

```
$street = 'Öhmsträße 2a';

if(preg_match('/\s+(\d+[a-z]?)$/i', trim($street), $matches) !== 0) {
    var_dump($matches);
} else {
    echo 'no house number';
}
```

1. `\s+` matches one or more space chars (blanks, tabs, etc.)
2. `(`...`)` defines a capture group which can be accesses in `$matches`
3. `\d+` matches one or more digits (2, 23, 235, ...)
4. `[a-z]` matches one character from a to z
5. `?` means it's optional (not every house number has a letter in it)
6. `$` means end of string, so it makes sure the house number is at the end of the string

Make sure you strip any spaces after the end of the house number with `trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

The u modifier can help sometimes for handling "extra" characters.

Comment: would this be the correct syntax? `/[a-zA-ZßäöüÄÖÜ .]*(?=[0-9])/u`

Comment: Yes. But if you would like to keep the number only. Then maybe it is easier to focus the number parts, and keep it. For example: preg_match('/(\d+).*?$/',$address, $matches) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this may be a character set or UTF-8 issue.

It would be a good idea to find out what version of PHP you're running too. If I recall correctly, full Unicode support came in around 5.1.x

Comment: It's PHP 5.2.19. I will do some research on encoding because I think that theres the problem too